# When user clicks on link I want to unzip file and then open it

Tags: php, javascript, html

I would be grateful for help concerning this issue:

User clicks on a link:
the link itself has the parameter that tells which file needs to be unzipped to /unzip folder. After a file is unzipped, I would like to open the file.

How can I do this? I have the unzip part coded already.

Comment: It's difficult to understand without observing the relevant code you're trying. Could you please post it?

Comment: If you receive the file name as parameter make sure you sanitize it, otherwise you will be vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Will the file be unzipped on the same location on the web server ? How would you open it ? Do you want the file to be opened **automatically** in your local computer or extracted in the webserver ?

Comment: Use: [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) — Send a raw HTTP header

Comment: The thing is that i have a zip file with a lot of files file1.doc, file2.doc file3.doc etc.. the link means for instance file3.doc but at this point it is still zipped. so when the user clicks the link i need to unzip this and extract file3.doc and open it automatically(preferably without the file download pop up-- well thats another question). i need to have these zipped because of a lot of files

Comment: that file download pop up is ok, just saw that the user can disable that..

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a following solution:

1. You create a folder on the server where you will unzip the files to.
2. You create an .htaccess file there which specifies your own php script as 404 Error handler
3. In your php script you parse URL and identify which file to unzip, unzip it and redirect user to the newly created file
4. If you need to clean the unizpped files, you can create a cronjob which will remove files older than a certain time

What you get from that is:

- File transfer from server to user is handled by web server
- You actually cache your work as 404 handler won't run if you have the file in place
- You can significantly lower the server load as this approach reduces the amount of operations performed on server side (when file exists)

The description above assumes Apache as a web server